# Download data from website, that requires login, with service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm building an application for a website that requires login. I have already implemented functionality that allows the user to login and data is downloaded and displayed.

I have to use a service that will poll the server every half hour and check if new data is available. I have a few design issues and not sure what the best way to implement this is.

1. If the session id expires, how should I hande this in the service?
2. The user is able to manually update the application, which means the same data can be downloaded twice. How should I avoid this?
3. When the user updates it's done in a asynctask from the same activity. Should I switch this to be done in a service as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ask user to log in again or cache the login details and do it automatically. Only you would know the best answer based on what you want the user experience to be.
2. If you can detect it is the same data then don't download it again. If you cannot, duplicating it would be probably unavoidable.
3. A service would work. You could also use an async task inside a retained fragment.

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html